# TaskTrackers are silently gone from JobTracker pool

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

We have run into an issue with our Hadoop cluster. There are 10 nodes (out of about 70) that the JobTracker has silently unsubscribed from its UI.

While these nodes used to be running jobs, now they are not listed by the JobTracker at all. Not under `Nodes`, `Blacklisted Nodes`, `Graylisted Nodes`, or `Excluded Nodes`.

The TaskTracker processes are still running on the hosts. I have checked that there is network connectivity and the ability to `ssh` between the JobTracker and the disappearing nodes.

In the logs I am seeing that recently we started to have a lot of failure cases like: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5 . There is a correlation between the `Jetty /mapOutput` errors and the TaskTrackers stopping.

Does anyone know what would cause a TaskTracker to fail silently rather than be put into the blacklisted nodes list?

I have dumped the TaskTracker threads with `jstack`.

It seems like the TaskTracker is trying to shutdown, but is waiting on something.

Deadlock Detection: No deadlocks found.

Thread 14005:

```
(state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.stop() @bci=105, line=973 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$ClientCache.stopClient(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client) @bci=47, line=191 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$ClientCache.access$500(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$ClientCache, org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client) @bci=2, line=140 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.close() @bci=19, line=238 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.access$600(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker) @bci=1, line=203 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.stopProxy(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.VersionedProtocol) @bci=11, line=439 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.close() @bci=34, line=283 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.close() @bci=8, line=328 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.closeAll() @bci=78, line=1446 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.closeAll() @bci=40, line=277 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$ClientFinalizer.run() @bci=0, line=260 (Interpreted frame)
```

Thread 18731:

```
(state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=156 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=1987 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=399 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$1.run() @bci=7, line=434 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=662 (Interpreted frame)
```

Thread 18730:

```
(state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=156 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=1987 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=399 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.server.tasktracker.userlogs.UserLogManager.monitor() @bci=4, line=131 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.server.tasktracker.userlogs.UserLogManager$1.run() @bci=4, line=66 (Compiled frame)
```

Thread 18729:

```
(state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner.run() @bci=4, line=93 (Interpreted frame)
```

Thread 18728:

```
(state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop() @bci=201, line=509 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.TimerThread.run() @bci=1, line=462 (Interpreted frame)
```

Thread 18724:

```
(state = IN_NATIVE)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(long, int, long, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(long) @bci=18, line=210 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(long) @bci=28, line=65 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(long) @bci=37, line=69 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(long) @bci=30, line=80 (Compiled frame)
 - org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect() @bci=615, line=457 (Compiled frame)
 - org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager.doSelect(int) @bci=24, line=190 (Compiled frame)
 - org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.accept(int) @bci=5, line=124 (Compiled frame)
 - org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run() @bci=151, line=706 (Compiled frame)
 - org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run() @bci=25, line=520 (Interpreted frame)
```

Thread 18671:

```
(state = IN_NATIVE)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(long, int, long, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(long) @bci=18, line=210 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(long) @bci=28, line=65 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(long) @bci=37, line=69 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(long) @bci=30, line=80 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select() @bci=2, line=84 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.run() @bci=33, line=333 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=59, line=886 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=28, line=908 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=662 (Interpreted frame)
```

Thread 18667:

```
(state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=156 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=1987 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=399 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.mapred.CleanupQueue$PathCleanupThread.run() @bci=47, line=130 (Compiled frame)
```

Thread 18661:

```
(state = BLOCKED)
```

Thread 18660:

```
(state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=44, line=118 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2, line=134 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() @bci=3, line=159 (Compiled frame)
```

Thread 18659:

```
(state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run() @bci=46, line=116 (Compiled frame)
```

Thread 18644:

```
(state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.lang.Thread.join(long) @bci=38, line=1186 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.join() @bci=2, line=1239 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks() @bci=87, line=79 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.run() @bci=0, line=24 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks() @bci=23, line=79 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Shutdown.sequence() @bci=26, line=123 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Shutdown.exit(int) @bci=96, line=168 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Runtime.exit(int) @bci=14, line=90 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.System.exit(int) @bci=4, line=904 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(java.lang.String[]) @bci=114, line=3722 (Interpreted frame)
```

Comment: were you using Amazon's EMR? If yes, were you using spot instances?

Comment: Hi Amar. No we were not using EMR. We have some EC2 machines as datanodes, but this problem is independent of the machine type.